# Datatable layout is messed up in Firefox

Tags: datatables

I am using Datatables and I am having an issue with the layout in Firefox. How do I fix my datatables. The select box is pushing my table to the side. The tables work fine in Chrome and Safari, just an issue with FF. Thanks for your help. [image]

Comment: I'm no CSS expert, but try adding clear:left to the select box

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a fiddle or @http://live.datatables.net/